# Find and replace '000L' from all rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to remove certain letters from part numbers but I'm having difficulties trying to get it working correctly.

This is where I'm at right now. It's non functional.

```
SELECT REPLACE(`part`, '[0-9]L', '') FROM `table` WHERE (`part ` LIKE '%[0-9]L')
```

Essentially say I have these five items:

D39J02GEN 
**20F934L** 
2984CPL 
29048L20GEN 
**1120934L**

I only want the ones in bold to be detected. So where they end in L, only if they have a number before the L.

Edit: this one gets close:

`` SELECT * FROM `table ` WHERE `part` REGEXP '^[0-9].*L'; ``

but still shows ones where there is anything after the L. This is also no closer to removing the letter L.

Comment: Replace function in MySQL cannot handle patterns or regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the value is at the end, then do:

```
SELECT LEFT(part, LENGTH(part) - 2)
FROM `table`
WHERE part REGEXP '[0-9]L$';
```

This would be much trickier if the pattern were in the middle of the string.

Comment: This works, but the slight change I'd make would be `LENGTH(part) - 1)` as I only need the last letter off the text but how would I then trim the last letter in one query?

Comment: *"I only need the last letter off the text but how would I then trim the last letter in one query? "* @Joe `SUBSTRING(REVERSE(part), 1, 1)` would display `L`

Comment: Thank you for your helpful replies. I will now use this query as sometimes I will need to strip more than 3 letters. ```UPDATE `t` SET `p` = REPLACE(`p`, 'GEN', '') WHERE `p` REGEXP '[0-9]GEN$';```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should also work if the match is always required at the end of the text.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM 
 t 
WHERE
   SUBSTRING(REVERSE(t.text_string), 1, 1) = 'L'
 AND
   SUBSTRING(REVERSE(t.text_string), 2) >> 0 <> 0
```

**Result**

```
| text_string |
| ----------- |
| 20F934L     |
| 1120934L    |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b4dYVkVouMd9JAeJhcZh9i/0)

**Note** 
`SUBSTRING(REVERSE(t.text_string), 2) >> 0` basically means `CAST(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(t.text_string), 2)  AS UNSIGNED)` here

Why this works?

I use MySQL's loose autocasting feature which can convert `439F02` in a `INT` `439` but it can't convert `PC4892` into a `INT` it would be converted into `0`

See the below resultset based on the query

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
 , SUBSTRING(REVERSE(t.text_string), 1, 1)
 , SUBSTRING(REVERSE(t.text_string), 2)
 , SUBSTRING(REVERSE(t.text_string), 2) >> 0 
 , SUBSTRING(REVERSE(t.text_string), 2) >> 0 <> 0 
FROM 
 t
```

**Result**

```
| text_string | SUBSTRING(REVERSE(t.text_string), 1, 1) | SUBSTRING(REVERSE(t.text_string), 2) | SUBSTRING(REVERSE(t.text_string), 2) >> 0 | SUBSTRING(REVERSE(t.text_string), 2) >> 0 <> 0 |
| ----------- | --------------------------------------- | ------------------------------------ | ----------------------------------------- | ---------------------------------------------- |
| D39J02GEN   | N                                       | EG20J93D                             | 0                                         | 0                                              |
| 20F934L     | L                                       | 439F02                               | 439                                       | 1                                              |
| 2984CPL     | L                                       | PC4892                               | 0                                         | 0                                              |
| 29048L20GEN | N                                       | EG02L84092                           | 0                                         | 0                                              |
| 1120934L    | L                                       | 4390211                              | 4390211                                   | 1                                              |
```

Here is a [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b4dYVkVouMd9JAeJhcZh9i/1) to see the above results for yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the extremely detailed post. I'm sure this will also help in the future if needed but for now I only need to update fields and strip letters under certain conditions. Thank you for your great help.